# Changes on SO user takes time to appear on meta user

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

Why does profile changes and reputation changes (+/-) on StackOverFlow take time to appear on metaStackoverflow?

Comment: caching it's always caching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reputation is synchronized *once an hour*. This is documented in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (**synchronized hourly**), though you earn separate badges.

Emphasis mine.